# Access constant in class

Tags: php, class

I try to access a constant in a class:

*file1.php*

```
[...]    
define('SUBDOMAIN','name');
require_once 'file2.php';
[...]
```

*file2.php*

```
[...]
class Gdl_Ute extends Response_Model {    
public $table = SUBDOMAIN.'zi_utp';

public function statuses()
{
[...]
```

I've used some variants like:

```
public function __construct()
{
self::$table = SUBDOMAIN.'zi_utp';
}
```

But there is always an error like:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'
```

or

```
syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE
```

Thanks very much for any hints! I've also read other similar questions on stackoverflow, but none has answered this problem correctly :/

**UPDATE**
Now I've test the following solutions:

*file2.php*

```
public $table;
public function __construct()
{
self::$table = SUBDOMAIN.'zi_utp';
}
```

OR

*file1.php*

```
define('SUBDOMAIN',$subdomain);
const SUBDOMAIN = $subdomain;
```

RESULT

```
Access to undeclared static property OR
syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE
```

Comment: You can only initialize variables to scalar values (or arrays). If you  just declare `public $table` then initialize in the constructor it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `const` to define your constant. have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)